# DYLD, dependent dylib '/usr/lib/swift/libswiftUniformTypeIdentifiers.dylib' not found

Tags: ios, swift, testflight, xcode12, dyld

TestFlight Beta App crashed on devices running below iOS14 with the below crash log,

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, dependent dylib '/usr/lib/swift/libswiftUniformTypeIdentifiers.dylib' not found for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3BC6B3A6-34C0-4BD7-8276-EB8D91B3F2EF/AppName.app/AppName', tried but didn't find: '/usr/lib/swift/libswiftUniformTypeIdentifiers.dylib' '/usr/local/lib/libswiftUniformTypeIdentifiers.dylib' '/usr/lib/libswiftUniformTypeIdentifiers.dylib'
Highlighted by Thread:  0

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000001   x2: 0x000000016f016060   x3: 0x00000000000000b8
    x4: 0x000000016f015c60   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x7362696c2f62696c  x11: 0x66696e5574666977
   x12: 0x6d726f66696e5574  x13: 0x6e65644965707954  x14: 0x2e73726569666974  x15: 0x00202762696c7964
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x0000000103be57f4  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016f015c60  x21: 0x00000000000000b8  x22: 0x000000016f016060  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x0000000103c0c000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000103c0c000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016f015c30   lr: 0x0000000103bf274c
    sp: 0x000000016f015bf0   pc: 0x0000000103beb17c cpsr: 0x00000000
   esr: 0x00000000  Address size fault

Binary images description not available

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef - corpse still valid ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

EOF
```

Based on Termination Description, I tried applying,

1. `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` set to `YES` for **Main Target**, `NO` for **Extensions**,
2. Run Path on extension already have `@executable_path/../../Frameworks`

Nothing works.

Upon checking that this framework uses SwiftUI and I have just added iOS14 Widget extension with SwiftUI.. But the deployment target for Widget is iOS14 only.

FYI - There are several Q/A's regarding **IMAGE NOT FOUND** error but I could not find any solution regarding this `libswiftUniformTypeIdentifiers.dylib`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: d=(-_-) Same here, don't give up!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, if we open and check our `/usr/lib/swift` directory:

1. There are a lot of `*.dylib` files, except that one mentioned.
2. It seems, those are part of `MacOS 11` and an update should fix the issue.
3. If for any reason an OS-update is not an option, we can lower `Catalyst` version, and instead update our swift-code to support this change, like:

```swift
let controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController
if #available(macCatalyst 14.0, *) {
    controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType.image])
} else {
    controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeImage as String], in: .import)
}
```